# Regex ignore multiple wrong placed quotes

Tags: regex

From this input:

```
""" "01-01-2000""" " ",""" "Bank123""" "", "" ""Example text" " "",
```

I want to extract:

```
01-01-2000
Bank123
Example text
```

I managed this:

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

But if fails if it comes to deal with many wrong placed quotes. Any ideas?

Comment: Try [`"\b(.*?)\b"`](https://regex101.com/r/i6Grv5/1)

Comment: Or, [`\B"\b(.*?)\b"\B`](https://regex101.com/r/i6Grv5/2). Can the values you want to extract contain `"`? Why did you use a regex that matches escaped `"`?

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: Hi, tried [`[^\s",]+(?:\s+[^\s",]+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/i6Grv5/4) yet? Please explain what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options to do so:

```
1) ([\d-\w\s][\d-\w\s]+)
2) ([\d-\w\s]{2,})
3) "\b(.+?)\b"
4) \b([^"]{2,})\b
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/jPXqKv/1

Test:

```
""" "01-01-2000""" " ",""" "Bank123""" "", "" ""Example text" " ""
```

Match:

```
Match 1
Full match  5-15    `01-01-2000`
Group 1.    5-15    `01-01-2000`
Match 2
Full match  28-35   `Bank123`
Group 1.    28-35   `Bank123`
Match 3
Full match  48-60   `Example text`
Group 1.    48-60   `Example text`
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you are interested in strings which:

- start with either a digit or a letter,
- followed by a (maybe empty) sequence of chars other than `"`.

So the intuitive solution is `[a-z\d][^"]*` with `gi` options
(global, case insensitive).

Answer (score 0):

For your given example, perhaps it could be an option to match a whitespace or a double quote zero or more times `[ "]*` to match what comes before the value between the inner double quotes.

Then match that double quote and capture in a group not a double quote or a newline `([^"\r\n]+)` using a negated character class.

At the end match the closing double quote followed by zero or more times a whitespace or a double quote which will match what comes after so the group does not match a whitespace between double quotes.

[`[ "]*"([^"\r\n]+)"[ "]*`](https://regex101.com/r/hZCf6Q/1)